# Java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.getEnvironment

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, java-8

I am trying to update the spring project so that it runs on Java 8. I updated spring core to 3.2.9 which has support for Jdk 8. I updated spring web to 3.2.9 as I was getting errors with 4.0. Post that, I updated spring beans to 3.2.9. Now, I am getting errors related to spring web:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.getEnvironment()Lorg/springframework/core/env/ConfigurableEnvironment;
    org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:87)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:123)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:422)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:352)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:402)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:316)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:282)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:126)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1789)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: You should upgrade all modules to the same version never mix jars from different versions of a framework that is trouble waiting to happen. The error you get is a clear indication you are mixing jars from different versions of Spring.